# How do you change the padding of an element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the following code

```
$("#numbers a").css({
"color":"white",
"text-decoration":"none",
"padding:":"5px"
});
```

The color and text-decoration change just fine, but the padding is not added to the element. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have a stray colon in your `padding` property which is causing it to not be recognized:

```
"padding:":"5px"
```

Remove it and it should work:

```
"padding":"5px"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the : is just a typo in to your post, you might be confused with padding and inline elements.

Your selector `"#numbers a"` hints you are referencing an anchor tag. An anchor tag is an inline element and inline elements do not have padding on all sides. [Nice article on padding|widths with inline elements](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/)

Comment: Inline elements *can* have padding on all sides. The padding does not adversely affect document flow, however.